# What kind of a problem is this?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

The problem can be stated as:

> I have $m$ liquids ($A_i$ is the amount of the $i$-th liquid) and $n$
>   tanks ($x_j$ is the volume of the $j$-th tank), and the task is to find
>   the best way to fill the tanks.

Additional information:

> 1. $A_i, x_j \in \mathbb{N}$
> 2. If we fit the tank $x_j$ with liquid $A_i$, then we are not allowed to fit it with anything else (e.g. we can not pour $2$l from $A_1$ and $3$l from $A_2$ into tank $x_1 = 10$).
> 3. The liquid $A_i$ can be distributed over several tanks (but watch 2.)

My first model was:

We have the following problem: solve for $(k_i)$

$$ 
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
\min & (k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2 + \cdots + k_n x_n - A_1) \\
\min & (k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2 + \cdots + k_n x_n - A_2) \\
\vdots & \\
\min& (k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2 + \cdots + k_n x_n - A_n)
\end{aligned} 
\right.
$$

$$
k_i > 0 \\
A_i > 0 \\
\min(...) > 0
$$

$k_i$ may be either $0$ or $1$. If $k_i$ is $1$ in some equation, it can only be $0$ in all other.
The $A_i$ and $x_i$ are known.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: can any of the expressions have multiple $k_i$ equal to $1$, except that those $k_i$ are then "exhausted"? Also, are the $x_i$ and $A_i$ all positive? If so then it seems the minimum would be all $k_i=0$. So I think I don't understand that aspect of the problem either.

Comment: @lan, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean that the $x_i>0$, but now I think I understand the problem better. Here I'll put my understanding in my own words. You have $n$ different liquids with volumes $A_i$ and $n$ tanks with volumes $x_i$. You want to put the liquids in tanks in such a way that every liquid is in a tank, no tank has more than one liquid, and the smallest possible amount of volume is wasted in each tank.

Comment: My question, then: why should it be possible to simultaneously minimize all $n$ assignments? I would think that you would instead want to minimize some *overall function* of the wasted volume, such as the sum of all the wasted volumes.

Comment: @mvw As far as I can tell, that is not explicitly forbidden, but it is effectively forbidden by the fact that the number of liquids equals the number of tanks, all the liquids must go somewhere, and distinct liquids are not permitted to mix. But yes, I had the same thought. I think my understanding must have some flaw, because at the moment the problem seems rather ill-posed.

Comment: First, number of liquids does not equals number of tanks. We can pour one liquid over several tanks. 
It is not always possible to fit all tanks and pour all liquids. But we need:
a) If pour liquid - minimise unused amount. b) each tank have to be used as much as it possible c) minimise amount of unused liguids

Comment: hah) it is not an optimal solution

Comment: @user1040320 How do you figure that the number of liquids does not equal the number of tanks? You used the same index $n$ for the largest index of the $A_i$ and the $x_i$. Did you intend to use $n$ for one and $m$ for the other, or something?

Comment: We need to revisit the pouring. If the tank fits 5 litres (x1=5) and $A=1$l what happens? Can it gef filled with $0.7$ litres and $0.3$ litres can go into another tank? Or does it get filled with just $1$l or does the pouring not happen, because the tanks get filled up fully and there is not enough  liquid (which is what I seem to have modeled). What are the allowed actions?

Comment: @lan, yes. N for liquids and M for tanks

Comment: @mvw only integers. It is better not to fit if tank is much bigger then liquid.

Comment: @mvw yes. No float values

Comment: Hem, if $k_i=0\text{ or }1$, and $k_i>0$, chances are high that $k_i=1$.

Comment: Why was this closed? It's a linear programming question and I could have said that!

Comment: It was probably closed because folks had question about the task. I tried to model this as LP but for the present form of the problem I had no luck so far. Either the objective function gets non-linear or I fail to model all constraints.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This might not be your problem, but I think it is quite close to it.

**Update:** Calculating a small example exposed a modeling error. I am trying to fix this.

**Update:** The solution has morphed into a round based procedure, where each round tries to pour as much liquid as possible until one runs out of free tanks or rest liquid. Sounds greedy. Will this yield an optimum? More examples needed.

**Update:** The greedy approach fails. It allocates a tank with the $1$l (total allocation $16$) while it should not and wait for the next round of allocation to reach an optimimum of $17$.

**First try:**

The equations for the $m$ liquid rests $r_i$ of the liquid $A_i$ could be modeled as:
$$ 
\left\{ 
\begin{align}
r_1 =& A_1 - (k_{11} x_1 + k_{12} x_2 + \cdots + k_{1n} x_n) \\
r_2 =& A_2 - (k_{21} x_1 + k_{22} x_2 + \cdots + k_{2n} x_n) \\
\vdots & \\
r_m =& A_m - (k_{m1} x_1 + k_{m2} x_2 + \cdots + k_{mn} x_n)
\end{align} 
\right.
$$
where each column vector of the matrix $k$ has at most one component with value $1$ and its other components have value $0$.

A non-zero matrix element $k_{ij}$ means fill tank $x_j$, and fill it with liquid from $A_i$. So this allows only tank fills from one source. It also means that tanks are either filled not at all or fully.

This means we have $n$ times $m+1$ choices to not place the $1$ at all or place it into the particular columns vector of $k$.

Constraints seem to be:
\begin{align}
r_i & \ge 0 \quad (?) \\
A_i &> 0 \\
k_{ij} &\in \{0, 1\} \\
x_i &> 0 \quad (?) \\
\end{align}

Optimization goal and objective function might be:
$$
\min_{k} r(k)
$$
where 
\begin{align}
r(k) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^m r_i \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m \left( A_i - \sum_{j=1}^n k_{ij} x_j \right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^m A_i - \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n k_{ij} x_j \\
\end{align}

which is equivalent to
$$
\max_k x(k)
$$
for 
$$
x(k) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n k_{ij} x_j 
$$

**Result**

The above problem can be formulated as integer linear program (ILP)
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & c^\top k \\
\mbox{w.r.t.} & c^\top k \le a \\
& \alpha_1^\top k \le 1 \\
& \quad \vdots \\
& \alpha_n^\top k \le 1 \\
& k_{ij} \in \{ 0, 1 \} 
\end{array}
$$
in $mn$ unknowns $k_{ij}$ rearranged as vector
$$
k = (k_{11}, \ldots k_{m1}, \ldots, k_{1n} \ldots k_{mn})^\top
$$
with cost vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$:
$$
c = (\underbrace{x_1, \ldots, x_1}_{m \times}, \ldots, 
\underbrace{x_n, \ldots, x_n}_{m \times})^\top
$$
constraint parameter $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with
$$
a = \sum_{i=1}^m A_i
$$
and the $n$ constraints $\alpha_j$ on the columns of the $k$-matrix:
$$
\alpha_j = (0,\cdots 0, \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{m \times}, 0 \cdots 0)^\top
$$
where for the $j$-th constraint vector $\alpha_j$ the $1$ values are from component $1 + (j-1) m$ to $m + (j-1) m$.

Instances of the above problem can be solved with many available lp solvers, e.g. see [lpsolve docs](http://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/).

**Example:**

The problem

$$
x = (5, 5, 10)^\top \\
A = (1, 7, 10)^\top 
$$

led to this solution with lpsolve:
$$
k = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
This means

- liquid from $A_3=10$ was poured into $x_1=5$
- tank $x_2=5$ was not used
- $A_1 = 1$ was poured in tank $x_3=10$
- $15$l were poured

What is wrong is that $x_3$ accounted for its full volume of $10$l while it got only $1$l. This is an error in the model.

It could have been prevented by enforcing that $k_{ij} = 0$ if $x_j > A_i$. 
This can be determined before optimization and should lead to drop that $k_{ij}$ from the variables or (maybe simpler) to add a constraint $\delta_{ij}^\top k = 0$ to enforce $k_{ij} = 0$.

In case of the example this leads to four additional constraints:

```
> add.constraint(lprec, c(1,0,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0), "=", 0)
> add.constraint(lprec, c(0,1,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0), "=", 0)
> add.constraint(lprec, c(0,0,1, 0,0,0, 0,0,0), "=", 0)
> add.constraint(lprec, c(0,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,0), "=", 0)
```

and a new solution

```
> get.objective(lprec)
[1] 15
> get.variables(lprec)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
```

$$
k = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

which means

- tank $x_1 = 5$ was not used
- liquid from $A_3 = 10$ was poured into $x_2=5$
- liquid from $A_2 = 7$ was poured into $x_3 = 10$
- $15$ litres were poured ($18-15=3$ not)

Ouch, again wrong. Only $7+5=12l$ were poured.

The objective function must be modified into
$$
x(k) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n k_{ij} \min(A_i, x_j)
$$

And we have to think about additional rounds to deal with the left-overs $A' = (1,0,5)$.

And we get rid of the last four constraints.

This gives

```
> delete.constraint(lprec, 8)
> delete.constraint(lprec, 7)
> delete.constraint(lprec, 6)
> delete.constraint(lprec, 5)
> set.objfn(lprec,c(1,5,5, 1,5,5, 1,7,10))
> solve(lprec)
[1] 0
> get.objective(lprec)
[1] 15
> get.variables(lprec)
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

$$
k = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

which means

- liquid from $A_3 = 10$ was poured into $x_1=5$
- tank $x_2=5$ was not used
- liquid from $A_3 = 10$ was poured into $x_3=10$

Again a modeling error, we can not pour $15$l from the $10$l in $A_3$.

Tricky. Adding constraints on the rows of $k$ so only one $1$ is allowed would mean that we allow at most one pour from a liquid into atmost one tank.

And we do not need the constraint $c^\top k \le a$ anymore, as we can not exceed $a$.

```
> add.constraint(lprec, c(1,0,0, 1,0,0, 1,0,0), "<=", 1)
> add.constraint(lprec, c(0,1,0, 0,1,0, 0,1,0), "<=", 1)
> add.constraint(lprec, c(0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,0,1), "<=", 1)
> solve(lprec)
[1] 0
> get.objective(lprec)
[1] 16
> get.variables(lprec)
[1] 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

$$
k = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

which means

- liquid from $A_1 = 1$ was poured into $x_1=5$
- liquid from $A_2 = 7$ was poured into $x_2=5$
- liquid from $A_3 = 10$ was poured into $x_3=10$
- $16$l were poured

That looks better. But this problem might be farther from the original problem.

**Result 2:**

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & c^\top k \\
\mbox{w.r.t.} & \alpha_1^\top k \le 1 \\
& \quad \vdots \\
& \alpha_n^\top k \le 1 \\
& \beta_1^\top k \le 1 \\
& \quad \vdots \\
& \beta_m^\top k \le 1 \\
& k_{ij} \in \{ 0, 1 \} 
\end{array}
$$
in $mn$ unknowns $k_{ij}$ rearranged as vector
$$
k = (k_{11}, \ldots k_{m1}, \ldots, k_{1n} \ldots k_{mn})^\top
$$
with cost vector $c \in \mathbb{R}^{mn}$:
$$
c = (\underbrace{\min(A_1,x_1), \ldots, \min(A_m,x_1)}_{m}, \ldots, 
\underbrace{\min(A_1,x_n), \ldots, \min(A_m,x_n)}_{m})^\top
$$
the $n$ constraints $\alpha_j$ on the columns of the $k$-matrix:
$$
\alpha_j = (0,\cdots 0, \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{m \times}, 0 \cdots 0)^\top
$$
where for the $j$-th constraint vector $\alpha_j$ the $1$ values are from component $1 + (j-1) m$ to $m + (j-1) m$.

And the $m$ constraints $\beta_i$ on the rows of the $k$-matrix:
$$
\beta_1 = (\underbrace{1, 0, \cdots, 0}_{m}, \underbrace{1, 0, \cdots, 0}_{m}, \underbrace{1, 0, \cdots, 0}_{m})^\top \\
\beta_2 = (\underbrace{0, 1, 0, \cdots, 0}_{m}, \underbrace{0, 1, 0, \cdots, 0}_{m}, \underbrace{0, 1, 0, \cdots, 0}_{m})^\top \\
\vdots
$$

where for the $i$-th constraint vector $\beta_i$ the $1$ values are at component $q m + i$ for $q \in \{ 0, \ldots, n-1 \}$.

**Interpretation of the above model:**

$t=\min(m,n)$ of the $m$ liquids are selected for $t$ of the $n$ tanks.
A pour is attempted each.

$k_{ij} = 1$ means: Of the liquid $A_i$ there will be $\min(A_i, x_j)$ litres poured into tank $x_j$.

**Several Rounds:**

One might interpret the above procedure as one round of several.

For the example we started with 
$$
x = (5,5,10)^\top \quad A = (1, 7, 10)
$$
and ended up with rest capacities and liquids
$$
x' = (4, 0, 0)^\top \quad A' = (0, 2, 0)  
$$
Also all tanks are used, there are no free tanks anymore, so we have to stop. Another stop condition would be that no liquid is available anymore.

Comment: the solution of a linear programming problem can be : $\infty$ (bad conditionned problem), a vertex, a segment, or a face of the admissible (multidimensional) polyedra. that's what you have to understand. thus for every linear programming problem having an optimum, there is a vertex being optimum, thus you just have to test them all (comparing the cost function) : there are at most $2^M$ vertices where $M$ is the number of variables. or you can do the simplex algorithm : a gradient descent , jumping from an admissible vertex to another.

Comment: by the way, there are special algorithms (with multiplicative updates) for non-negative matrix invertion.

Comment: The above tried to formulate a well posed integer linear programming problem for boolean valued unknowns.

Comment: mvw, that's good

Comment: Where each column vector of the matrix k has at most one component with value 1 and its other components have value 0. - I don't see it in the linear model. Do I miss something?

Comment: That constraint is translated into the inequalities $\alpha_j^\top k \le 1$. Each of these will lead to a sum over the $m$ components of the $j$-th column vector of the $k$ matrix.

Comment: @mvw, now I see

Comment: @mvm, please can we talk in Skype or anywhere else?

Comment: The basic idea here is to convert the matrix $k$ into a vector $k$  by listing the components column-wise. The goal is to cast the problem into the well-hung standard form of a (integer) linear programming problem, which can be fed into some solver. You could try it for a small example (not to large $m$ and $n$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26043/discussion-between-mvw-and-user1040320).

Comment: I didn't see the "boolean unkowns", thus with boolean variables it can be expressed as @mvw said as an integer linear programming (not so different from normal linear programming, but with constraint relaxation and backtracking), or preferably (in my opinion) as a SAT problem (which means you'll have to explain to the SAT solver what is an addition of k bits numbers :) ). look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_cut for integer linear programming algorithm

Comment: @reuns please provide more details if possible

Comment: @mvw really tricky question, yes?)
I was trying own model - but meet the same problem as you.

Comment: now I think I should solve it using heuristics and brute force

Comment: I would like to clean up the problem statement first. Otherwise you end up solving a different problem. Let us discuss this later.

Comment: @mvw, any example for result 2? I don't understand it

Comment: It is the model for the last example given. It has the new objective function which makes sure that each pour from liquid $A_i$ into tank $x_j$ uses $\min(A_i, x_j)$ litres (so only what fits in a tank) and the old constraints that there is at most one $1$ per column and the new constraints that there is at most one $1$ per row of the $k$ matrix.

Comment: Good, but one 1 per row is not a solution.

Comment: It is a different problem. Running this several rounds might be helpful. Lets have a chat later. I need a break from this, to get a clear mind.

Comment: @mvw thanks. I'll try to run several rounds.

Comment: If we fit tank x_1 with liquid a_1, then we are not allowed to fit it with anything else

Comment: Ok. Seems to me then that this might have been one of the two optimal solutions. You should think of a somewhat larger example problem to sink the teeth in.

Comment: I'll try to get more examples.

Comment: mvw, optimal solution is fit 7 litres to 5,5 tanks, fit 10 litres to 10 tank. Or fit 7 litres to 10 tank, fit 10 litres to 5,5 tanks. See?

Comment: Yes, the greedy approach fails here.

Comment: I stucked =\ 
I am not sure it is possible to solve it via linear programming models.

Comment: I am pessimistic too.

Comment: I am going to try to solve it via brute force. No other ideas right now.

Comment: can you join the chat, i still have questions on the task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26088/discussion-between-mvw-and-arteme).